# Tables for sports teams and fixtures in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, mysql-workbench

I have a table in MySQL for teams. It is set up as follows;

```
TEAM
team_id
team_name
team_logo
```

I also have tables called fixtures and venues.

```
FIXTURES
fixtures_id
fixture_text
fixture_time
fixture_date
competition

VENUE
venue_id
venue_name
venue_location
```

I am building my database using an EER diagram in MySQL Workbench which automatically assigns foreign keys upon the adding of relationships between the tables. My question is a simple one but it is one I am slightly confused on. I am wondering if the relationship between the TEAM and FIXTURE table is a One to Many or a Many to Many (which would automatically create a join table). Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can one team be associated with many fixtures? Can one fixture be associated with many teams?

Comment: One team can only be associated with a single fixture on a given date but over the course of a season a team can have many fixtures

Comment: Still, sounds like many-to-many to me :-) IMO, as a rough rule, if you think that there's any chance that a relationship is many-to-many, then design it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two teams play in one fixture.
One team plays many fixtures.
It's many to many.

Comment: One team can only play in one fixture on a given date - does this change things??

Comment: No, it does not.
It plays only one game on a given date but has many fixtures in current season (as an example).

Answer (score 0):

It's a slightly odd one, although you could (and someone has) argue that more than one team plays in one fixture, and one team plays in many fixtures, so it is many to many, I think this is too literal, if a fixture only ever has two teams then from a database point of view it is one to many, you don't need a junction table, you can just have two foreign key columns on your fixture table, e.g. `HomeTeamID`, `AwayTeamID`, or simply `Team1ID`, `Team2ID`. It is superfluous use of a junction table unless the number of teams per fixture is variable.

Comment: This is my thinking too but it is confusing - see the answers below where a different point of view is put across - there is logic in both